# Add text between 3 rows

Tags: excel, vba

Every week, I receive a report on the operations, and I have to make them presentable, between each operation, they are separated by 3 line breaks
What I would like to do is to add the titles between the 3 lines (on the second line)

Any ideas ?  The text in grey is what i want in the end (see screenshot)

```
Sub test()
 
 
 Dim K As Integer
 
 Set ws = Worksheets("DATA")
    
    lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row ' last data row
  '  K = 0
    For I = 1 To lastrow  ' all rows until last data row
    K = 1
        
        If ws.Cells(I, 3).Value = "" Then  ' column A, check if blank
           ws.Cells(I + K, 2).Value = "Total" ' set text
        '   ws.Cells(i, 3).Value = "Market"
         '   ws.Cells(i, 1).Value = "DATE UTC"

      End If
    Next

> End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this

```vb
Sub test()
 
    Dim rng As Range, ws As Worksheet, lastRow As Long
    
    Set ws = Worksheets("DATA")
    lastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row ' last data row
    
    Set rng = ws.Range("A1:C3")  'start checking here
    
    Do While rng.Row < lastRow-2
        If Application.CountA(rng) = 0 Then  'is the range empty?
            With rng.Rows(2)                 'work on the second row
                .Value = Array("Date UTC", "Total", "Market")
                .Interior.Color = RGB(200, 200, 200)
            End With
            Set rng = rng.Offset(3) 'next block to check
        Else
            Set rng = rng.Offset(1)
        End If
    Loop
 
End Sub
```